# Default text for optional dropdown menu

Tags: gui-design, selection

My app has a dropdown for a "Reason." Most users will/should select a reason but they do not have to.

We could have the default choice be `Select a reason...` to increase odds of people picking one. See [SO Q](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38928/adding-select-as-first-option-placeholder-of-dropdown-list)

**But how to indicate that it is fine to not choose a reason?**

Should we have the first selection be `(none)` or `(no reason)`?

Other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your app/form has mostly required input fields and the minority is optional you can **mark the optional input** accordingly.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhcFZI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>